# Underscore.js sortBy results wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, underscore.js

I have used underscore.js sortBy collection but it creating for sorting json with specific key. type of key can be number,text or date.

```
var arr = [  
    {"NodeName)":"Drama"},
    {"NodeName":"Song"},
    {"NodeName":"Jokes"},
    {"NodeName":"movie  "},
    {"NodeName":"music"},
    {"NodeName":"Main"},
    {"NodeName)":"Random"},
    {"NodeName":"Silent"},
    {"NodeName":"travel"},
    {"NodeName":"udefined"}];

var testSortBy = _.chain(arr).sortBy("NodeName").value();
```

result show the below:

```
Jokes
Main
Silent
Song
movie  
music 
travel 
udefined
Drama
Random
```

but the result should be like the following:

```
Drama
Jokes
moive
music
Main
Random
Silent
Song  
travel
udefined
```

i guess the issue can be uppercase and lower case issue. how can i avoid this issue?

Comment: You have "NodeName)" as the key of Drama and Random. Is this a typo or is it causing the behavior?

Comment: Remove the parenthesis mentioned by zvona and it should work.

Comment: The parenthesis added by mistake in this question but i didn't add this on code so result is still same

Answer (score -1):

Using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqjs.com)

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tford/xxpcqt90/)

Sorts on values in your array.

```
var result = jinqJs().from(arr).orderBy([{field: 0}]).select();
```

Here it doesnt matter that the keys are different, just the values are sorted. But keep in mind javaScript is case sensative and some of your values are caps and lowercase.